# Formula for euclidean distance between two normalized points with given angle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, angle, spheres

Consider the unit-ball in Dimension $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Say I know two normalized vectors (thus 'pointing' on two points $p$ and $q$ on the unit sphere) such that the angle between them is either $\alpha$ or $\beta$.

From this I want to calculate the euclidean distance between the two points $p$ and $q$. It is clear that there are only two-possible distances and that the distance heavily depends on $\alpha$ and/or $\beta$.

I believe that there already is some formula for this but I didn't find any, neither i came up with one.

I added an example with [in dimension $2$ and angle $\alpha$ for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlarP.jpg) The distance I want to find is the blue line between $p$ and $q$ for known $\alpha$.

Comment: Can you work out the 2-dimensional problem?

Comment: What do you need exactly?

Comment: Do you know the law of cosines?

Comment: Since you have two points, all you need to know is what happens in the two-dimensional case. Just draw a plane through these points. Hence, if you understand your own example setting, you are done.

Comment: How you define the position of the points?